# Why will the current be zero between X and Y, the connecting wire between two loops, in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Circuit Picture]

The existence of a voltage source between the two points indicates that there is a potential difference, so why would the two loops be independent and zero current flow through the connecting wire?

Comment: Currents flow in **loops**. Can you point out a loop that involves the 5 V voltage source? I cannot. Indeed the potential voltage at \$y\$ is 5 V higher than at \$x\$ but does that mean a current flows?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks, I get it now!

Comment: Can *can* flow under *transient* conditions. But, once enough charges have accumulated on one side, the potential rises and flow eventually stops. The question implicitly assumes that the solution under *steady state* is what is being asked. Though the answers say that current always flows in *loops*, the loop need *not* be made of a physical wire. A typical example is a one wire antenna. See also [Displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) where current completes the loop even though a physical conductor is absent in a section of the *loop*.

Comment: @AJN Yes, that was the first thought in my mind - the implicit condition that the circuit must be in a balanced state wrt potential and the loops must then become independent, however I couldn't exactly understand the end of such a transient state - the answers here have helped clear that confusion up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current always flows in a circuit; what goes in must return equally out the other side.

The connection between your loops has no return path; no current can get out, so no current can get in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not 100% convinced from answers and you are more mathematics oriented than physics try to consider an additional loop covering the XY segment:

[image]

you can see that the current in XY is I3-I3=0.